# Using Java, Trying to display a scrollable list of jbuttons with images, but text shows instead of buttons

Tags: java, swing

Let me describe my problem in more details. I have searched A LOT and tried many different approaches, using `validate()` and using `JLabels` instead of `JButtons`, but my mistake must be somewhere else because no matter which approach I try, I get the same error each time. The console shows no error, the program runs fine but the `JButton`s or `JLabel`s show up as text. From what I've read this should be working fine. I'm missing something for sure.. Please help me out, thanks ! :)

Here's the buttons showing up as text : https://i.stack.imgur.com/faK3Y.png

Here are the important parts of code... I've cut pieces of it because there's a lot of code...

```
public class MasterViewport implements MouseListener, ActionListener, ItemListener, ListSelectionListener {
    JScrollPane tileSelectorScrollPane;
    JFrame tMapEditor;
    ArrayList<Tile> tileArray = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    JButton[] selectorTiles = new JButton[255];
    DefaultListModel<JButton> tileList;
    JList<JButton> tileSelector;
    ...

// lower in the code...
public Container createContentPane() {

    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    tileList = new DefaultListModel<JButton>();
    tileSelector = new JList<JButton>(tileList);
    tileSelector.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    tileSelector.setOpaque(true);
    tileSelector.setVisible(true);
    tileSelectorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(tileSelector);
    contentPane.add(tileSelectorScrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);

    return contentPane;
}

//Now the method where the user selects a file in the select file dialog
//It's where it happens... As i confirm file selection, buttons show up as text.

...
while (!mapCreated) {
    createMap = newMapFile.showDialog(tMapEditor, "Create");
    if (createMap == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        newMapFileName = newMapFile.getSelectedFile();
            if (!newMapFileName.getName().endsWith(".map")) {
                newMapFileName = new File(newMapFileName.getAbsolutePath() + ".map");
            }
            File[] dirMapFileNames = newMapFile.getCurrentDirectory().listFiles();
            BufferedImage bimg = null;
            String currentFileName = "";
            int width = 0, height = 0;
            String legendStr = "";
            char ch = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dirMapFileNames.length; i++) {
                if (newMapFileName.equals(dirMapFileNames[i])) {
                    mapFileAlreadyExists = true;
                }
                if (ch <= 255) {
                    if (dirMapFileNames[i].getName().endsWith(".png")) {
                        try {
                            bimg = ImageIO.read(dirMapFileNames[i]);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        width = bimg.getWidth();
                        height = bimg.getHeight();
                        if (width == 32 && height == 32) {
                            tileImageFound = true;
                            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(dirMapFileNames[i].toString());
                            selectorTiles[ch] = new JButton("test", icon);
                            selectorTiles[ch].setOpaque(true);
                            selectorTiles[ch].setVisible(true);
                            Tile t = new Tile(ch, selectorTiles[ch]);
                            tileArray.add(t);
                            tileList.addElement(selectorTiles[ch]);
                            ch++;
                            legendStr = legendStr + "!" + ch + dirMapFileNames[i].getName();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ...

//Creating and showing the UI..

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame tMapEditor = new JFrame("Tile Map Editor");
    MasterViewport masterViewport = new MasterViewport();
    tMapEditor.setJMenuBar(masterViewport.createMenuBar());
    tMapEditor.setContentPane(masterViewport.createContentPane());
    tMapEditor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    tMapEditor.setSize(800, 480);
    tMapEditor.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Why do "new ImageIcon(dirMapFileNames[i].toString())" when you previous did "bimg = ImageIO.read(dirMapFileNames[i])"? Why not just use "new ImageIcon(bimg)"?

Comment: Don't add components to the JList; "tileList.addElement(selectorTiles[ch]);"; instead use a POJO, Wah contains the image and text, then use a ListCellRenderer to display them the way you want to, for example, the DefaultListCellRenderer is based on a JLabel

Comment: I did use new ImageIcon(bimg) before but it did not solve the problem, anyhow, I'll put it back ^_^.  I'll have too look into the Renderer too yes, thanks !

Comment: It's only the fact that you're double loading the image, which seems odd, that's all

Answer (score 3):

You can't add buttons to a JList. A JList just paints images of the component.

Instead, add an `Icon` to the `JList`. The JList supports a default renderer for Icons.

If you need a custom class you can also create a `TileIcon` that extends `ImageIcon` to hold your extra properties.

If you need real components, then don't use a JList. Instead use a JPanel with a `GridLayout` and add your buttons to the panel.

Comment: Thanks, if I take the "real components" option I'll be able to add images to the buttons on the GridLayout ? :)  I'm trying to have a scrollable list of clickable images where only one can be toggled at a time. just like selecting a color to paint with basically. It's just instead of painting, I'll be clicking on squares in the other viewport which wlll replace them with what was selected in the first viewport.

Comment: @Flip, You can use real components or you can use a JList which also supports selection of a single item in the list. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information. I suggest you are read the sections from the tutorial on `How to Use Buttons` and ` How to Use GridLayout` for some Swing basics.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this :

```
static class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
    public MyCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value.getClass().equals(JLabel.class)) {
            JLabel label = JLabel.class.cast(value);
            setIcon(label.getIcon());
            setBorder(label.getBorder());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```